# php mysqli audio file upload issues

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

Ive got this very simple page for uploading audio files in a db. But I cant figure out why its not working. As per my observation everything's fine with this code as well as the DB table. **When I click on browse and upload an audio, it keeps saying no file selected**

[image]
 **Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form. The file will not be sent**

my directory structure (/var/www/html/audio_upload):-

```
index.php, upload.php, uploads
```

my db & table code:-

```
mysql> create database audiolibdb;
mysql> use audiolibdb;
mysql> create table audios
    -> (id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    -> filename varchar(50)
    -> );
```

my index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype"multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="audiofFile"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Audio" name="save_audio"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my upload.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_audio']) && $_POST['save_audio']=="Upload Audio")
{
        $dir='uploads/';
        $audio_path=$dir.basename($_FILES['audioFile']['name']);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audioFile']['tmp_name'],$audio_path))
        {
                echo 'upload succesfull';
                saveAudio($audio_path);
        }
}


function saveAudio($fileName)
{
        $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','audiolibdb');
        if(!$conn)
        {
                die('server not connected');
        }

        $query="insert into audios(filename)values('{$fileName}')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn)>0)
        {
                echo "audio file path saved in DB";
        }

                mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Can you pls help me with this -- "When I click on browse and upload an audio, it keeps saying no file selected"

Comment: Where does it say that? Maybe post a screenshot to show the message?

Comment: @Dharman added the screenshot of error

Comment: That is your form. I assume you submitted one form and the form refreshed and lets you select another file. What is wrong with that? What is your expectation here? HTML forms usually do not have any memory.

Comment: @Dharman my upload/ directory is empty as well as mysql table also empty. Nothing there !!

Comment: You need to do some debuggin yourself. Try adding an `echo 'here';` line by line in your code and see at which point you can't reach this statement. Also see my second comment to check how to enable PHP errors.

Comment: @Dharman Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form. The file will not be sent.

Comment: In your form, you have defined no action. You should modify it to **action="upload.php"**

Comment: @nacho Done , but now upload.php page opens, with blank page and still the uploads folder is empty !!

Comment: @Dharman adding echo 'here'; didnt help much, Im a noob, thats why struggling !! Pls help

Comment: @nacho  its still not working, pls help !!!

Comment: @Dharman  its still not working, pls help !!!

Comment: Do you get any error or something?

Comment: @nacho did you try running it on your system ?  I cant see any error